# How to populate the dropdown list from database in mvc? Need to show names from database in dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I tried quite some things but always got error "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'SiteId'."

I want it to populate from database in my layout partial page.

Controller

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult PopulateDropDown()
        {
            //var sitename = GetSites();
            //SiteListViewModel slvm = new SiteListViewModel();
            List<SiteListViewModel> names = _db.Sites.Select(n => new SiteListViewModel { SiteId = n.SiteId, SiteName = n.Name }).ToList();
            ViewBag.All = names;
            return PartialView("_Layout", names);       
        }
```

View

```
 @Html.DropDownList("SiteId", ViewBag.All as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Model

```
public class SiteListViewModel
    {
        public int SiteId { get; set; }
        public string SiteName { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SiteNames { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get it after making these changes. By keeping the list passed by selectlistitem in both view and model.
Controller

```
 List<SelectListItem> names = _db.Sites.Select(n => new SelectListItem { Text = n.SiteId.ToString(), Value = n.Name }).ToList();
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownList("All", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.All)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you're passing the list as part of your model, there's no need to add it to ViewBag too...

Secondly, you've got `List<SiteListViewModel>` as your model, but the DropDown component requires you to have a list of `List<SelectListItem>`...

If you want to simply flatten multiple lists to a single list use the following:

`Model.SelectMany(x => x.SiteNames).ToList()` remember to add `@using System.Linq` to the top of your view.

Once you've got this, you can do the following on your Razor page:

`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SiteId, Model.SelectMany(x => x.SiteNames).ToList(), "Placeholder Text goes here.")`

Comment: I'm not a wizard, what's the error? Did you include the @using statement as stated in the answer?

Comment: Yes, I used the @using statement. It says no definition of Many is found and then red line appears and it does not build. I have now solved it but now I'm trying to populate dropdown in my shared layout page and it gives me this error " There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'All'."